# How to differentiate between possessive pronouns and adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, word-order, possessives, personal-pronouns, possessive-pronouns

How to use possessive pronouns and possessive adjectives?  For example, which is correct:

> Is this your luggage?

or

> Is this yours luggage?

Comment: Can you provide some examples that are confusing you?  For each example, please mention which category you guess the example belongs to.

Comment: Is this your luggage OR Is this yours luggage ?

Comment: Would you also like to know about "Is this luggage yours?"

Comment: They are both pronouns. Your first example is fine: "your" is called a **dependent genitive pronoun** functioning as a **determiner**. Your second example is ungrammatical: "yours" is an **independent genitive pronoun**, which means it does not require a following noun; instead you could say: "Is this luggage yours?"

Answer (score 2):

*My,your,his,her,its, our, their* are possessive adjectives or dependent genitive pronouns used as determiners **before nouns**.

> This is **my** book.

*Mine,yours,his,hers,ours,theirs* are possessive pronouns or independent genitive pronouns (thanks BillJ).They don't require nouns after them.

> The book is mine. Is that car yours?

Answer (score 0):

The first case is correct : "Is this your luggage"

'Yours' is a pronoun, so it should not be followed by a noun or noun phrase.

'Your' is a determiner and must be followed by a noun, completing a noun phrase.

Answer (score 0):

"Your" always goes before the noun. *Is this your luggage?*

"Yours" always goes alone. *Is this yours?* or *Is this luggage yours?*